# Is there a way of restricting Particlesbg to only component so that it doesn't cover the entire App.vue background

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, components

How do I restrict Particles-bg to only one component so that it doesn't cover the entire App.vue background, but the component where I want the animation to be ?
I installed the library, and imported it into my project globally through main.js. I am rendering it through the Main.vue component. The problem is the animation is flowing into the other components as well, I only want it to stay within the Main.vue one only.

This is the code showing how its being rendered from Main.vue.

```
 <template>
    <div class="intro-container">
       <particles-bg  type="custom" :bg='true' :config='config' />         
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
import { ParticlesBg } from "particles-bg-vue";

export default {
    name: 'Main',
    components:{ 
        ParticlesBg
    },
    data(){
        return{
            config:{
                num: [3, 20],
                rps: 1,
                life: [2, 2],
                v: [5, 10],
                tha: [-50, 40],
                rotate: [0, 20],
                alpha: [0.1, 0.2],
                scale: [1, 1],
                position: "center",
                color: ["#808080", "#808080"],
                cross: "dead", 
                g: 5, 
                random: 2,
                force:[2, -1],
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is, but you have to provide a [mcve] showing how you implemented it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: `.intro-container { position: relative }` should work.